# Are questions about Games on- or off- topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, public-beta

I ask a question about a game : https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/5500/what-is-the-killer-webgame

Someone has downvoted my question because he says this is not about game.

A game is an app, so a webgame should be a webapp?

I think someone interested in the social aspect of the webapps should be interested in the game application where I think there is still a lot to find out.

Answer (score 5):

I would say that web games are off-topic, in the same way that desktop games are off-topic for [Super User](http://superuser.com).

Whether they're on-topic for the [Gaming](http://gaming.stackexchange.com) Stack Exchange site is a question for that community.